# How to access the parent scope within a directive link

Tags: angularjs

So on the angular documentation website, you can define Tobias and Jeff

```
angular.module('docsTransclusionExample', [])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Tobias';
}])
.directive('myDialog', function() {
  return {
   restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: 'my-dialog.html',
    link: function (scope, element) {
      scope.name = 'Jeff';
    }
  };
});
```

If you do The name is {{name}} it'll say

```
The name is Tobias
```

I'm trying to access Tobias in the link function. From inside the link function, how would I get the $scope.name value equal to Tobias?

Comment: The `$parent` is the answer, as in the answer of Ufuk Hacıoğulları, but think twice if you *really* want to do this - it breaks the encapsulation of your directive. A much better approach is to pass any data you want as parameter, e.g. `scope: { parentName: '=' }` and then `<my-dialog parent-name="name">`.

Comment: Thank you Nikos! The directive's currently working with scope: false and no transclusion. In that case, how would I access $scope.name? Would it just be $scope.name? Would I need to pass $scope into the parameter of the link function?

Comment: Seeing `scope: false` "communicates" to me that the there is a common/flat "namespace" among the directive and its parent. In this case having two "things" called `name` does not make sense - it is like asking "why can't I have 2 `var`s with the same name in a JS function". What I am trying to say is that you should consider if this needs some kind of redesign.

Comment: Interesting. In my use case I'm just trying to get the $scope.name=Tobias value within the directive.

Comment: If `scope: false`, then you just read it. The problem is what do you mean/want with the line `scope.name = 'Jeff'`?

Comment: Nothing actually. Just want to read Tobias from within the directive and it's not working for some reason...

Answer (score 10):

Since the scope is isolated `scope: {},` directive creates a new child scope. In this case the only way to directly access parent scope property is to use scope `$parent`, reference to parent scope object. For example:

```
link: function(scope, element) {
    scope.name = 'Jeff';
    scope.parentName = scope.$parent.name; // Tobias
}
```

However this is not ideal. This is why you may want to consider more flexible approach:

```
<my-dialog name="name"></my-dialog>
```

and define a scope configuration as:

```
scope: {
    parentName: '=name'
}
```

Comment: Nice! How would I access $scope.name === Tobias if scope: false? (Instead of scope: {}, transclude: true)

Comment: If `scope: false` then directive does not create new isolated scope, but instead uses the same scope where it is defined. It means that you can access `Tobias` as `scope.name`.

Comment: No dollar sign? Do I still put scope as a parameter or $scope as a parameter? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: In link function you can name parameters whatever you like, they are not injected like in controller functions for example, where the naming is important because Angular looks up for services with exact names. In link function there is no injection, Angular passes parameters in fixed order: the first is scope, then element, then attributes.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use $parent property of the the scope:

```
scope.$parent.name = 'Jeff';
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you tell me why scope does need a dollar sign? It's scope instead of $scope. Should I add a dollar sign to the parameter?

Answer (score 3):

As you have used `transclude:true`, you can omit `scope:{}` if you do not have any local variables. Putting `scope:{}` does not make sense.

so the declaration would be like following

```
angular.module('docsTransclusionExample', [])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Tobias';
}])
.directive('myDialog', function() {
  return {
   restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: 'my-dialog.html',
    link: function (scope, element) {
      // scope.name = 'Jeff';
      // if name is in your parent scope, you should be able to get it here
      console.log(scope.name);
    }
  };
});
```

If you look at the template you will see `ng-transclude` directive has been used, this means where in template the parent scope's variables will be used there. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure the transclusion is even necessary but you make a good point! I tried this with the hope that it would fix my problem, and am getting "cannot read SomeProperty value of undefined" in console. I have scope: false and think I'm doing everything you have written. I'll double check...

Comment: *I'm not sure transclusion is necessary because I don't fully understand it yet and the directive was working without transclusion declared

Comment: if you use transclude, just omit scope (not false, just don't put it). transclude actually brings parent scope into directive. if you think of `ng-repeat` directive that wraps around your directives/templates but brings the values you have in `ng-repeat`'s scope.

Answer (score 3):

you can get it through $parent like this:

```
link: function (scope, element) {
  scope.name = 'Jeff';
  console.log(scope.name);
  console.log(scope.$parent.name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just wondering why would you want something like this.

This way you're creating a deppendency between the controller and the directive that shouldn't exist.

If you need input data on your directive, declare it explicitly.

Comment: Thank you, Alex. I don't think the transclusion or scope: {} are necessary for what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm using an already created directive that works without scope: {}. I'm just wondering how to access the controller's $scope.variable value in my directive.

Comment: But it's exactly that the "problem". When you access the parent scope from within your directive, you're creating a deppendency. If you move that directive into another page with a different controller the behavior will not be the same.
You should always supply data to the directive via attributes, never through discovery.
Another reason for this is testing.Having this kind of "deppendencies" makes it hard to write tests to your directive.